# How to format the output of ls?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to output all headers in a directory. There is one entry per line and each line should begin with four whitespaces and should end with a whitespace and a '\' character.

```
____header1.h_\
____header2.h_\
____header3.h_\
```

I already figured out how to make the output one entry per line.

```
ls -1 *.h
```

But I do not know how to do the formatting. Where should I look to learn more complicated formatting?

EDIT:

All the scripts in all the answers produce the desired output. I wish I could accept all answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -l *.h|awk '/\.h/{print "    "$0" \\"}'
```

Or in a more simple way in awk:

```
> ls -1 *.h | awk '$0="    "$0" \\"'
```

Tested :

```
> ls -1 *.hh 
Algorithms.hh
Timer.hh
a.hh
> ls -1 *.hh | awk '/\.hh/{print "    "$0" \\"}'
    Algorithms.hh \
    Timer.hh \
    a.hh \
>
```

Or you can use perl:

```
ls -1 *.h | perl -plne '$_="    ".$_." \\";'
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `printf` and shell globbing rather than attempt to format `ls` output.

Try something like:

```
$ printf '    %s \\\n' *.h
    a.h \
    b.h \
    c.h \
```

`ls` is really meant as an "interactive" tool for humans, avoid using it for anything else.

Comment: Thank you! The printf you are suggesting is this one http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf ? I am confused. Is it a C function? Can you call C functions from the shell just like that? Of course your solution works.

Comment: It's not the C function, it's a standard POSIX shell utility (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html). Bash implements it as a builtin too, so this is cheaper than anything involving pipes, sed, ls or anything else. As for parsing the output of ls, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Not http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf , MAT meant http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf :-)

Answer (score 8):

see

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -iname "*" -printf "%h,%f,%CY-%Cm-%Cd %CT,%s,%u,%M\n"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ls -1 *.h | sed 's/^/    /' | sed 's/$/ \\/'
```

Alternatively, you could say:

```
ls -1 *.h | sed 's/.*/    & \\/'
```

Comment: why starting two `sed` processes? `ls -1 *.h  | sed 's|^\(.*)$|    \1 \\|'` should do the trick with less ressources.

Comment: @umläute Added another version to save a few more characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l *.h|rev|ts "\\"|rev|ts "   "
```

( if ls output is not an interactive terminal, it will display filenames line by line)